# Getting search count in java from an array after comparing against the user input

Tags: java, arrays, loops, joptionpane

I am supposed to create an output similar to this:

[image: Expected Output]

I have organized my data into an array. To put it simply, I have organized it to
with 8 different POIBook with its individual data.

```
POIBook[i] = new POI(Type, Place, Rating)
```

I have no problems calling the right array according to the user input into a `JOptionpane` display.

However, I have problems trying to determine the total number of search and the search result the user is currently at. Eg. Search 1 of 3

How do I get the total number of the search result and the number the user is currently at?

**Edit: To add in the context of the question.**

The user will enter a search query in `JOptionpane` and it will search and return the array containing the search result. For example, searching for "Excitement" will return POIBook[4] , [5] and [6] as a `JOptionpane` display and as per the output expected in the picture above.

**Need help on the following:**

> How do I show that that 'Search Result - 1/3' when POIBook [4] is returned? and 'Search Result - 2/3' when POIBook[5] is returned etc.?
>
> At the point of display, we will need to know there are 3 results of "excitement" type and it is currently showing the 1st result out of 3.

```
public static void dataPOI() {
    
    POIBook[0] = new POI("Sightseeing", "River Safari","Wildlife, Panda Bear, Cruise",4.0);
    POIBook[1] = new POI("Sightseeing", "Singapore Flyer","Fly!",3.5);
    POIBook[2] = new POI("Sightseeing", "Gardens by The Bay","Flower Dome, Cloud Forest",3.5);
    POIBook[3] = new POI("Shopping", "Orchard Road","Ion, Mandarin Gallery",4.0);
    POIBook[4] = new POI("Excitement", "Universal Studios","Battlestar Galactica, Puss in Boots",4.5);
    POIBook[5] = new POI("Excitement", "Marina Bay Sands","Casino, Sky Park Observation Deck",4.0);
    POIBook[6] = new POI("Excitement", "Resorts World Sentosa","Trick Eye Museum, Adventure Cove",4.5);
    POIBook[7] = new POI("Night Life", "Night Safari","Wildlife, Tram Ride",4.5);

}
```

My code is as follows.

```
public static void search() {
    

    String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your type of attraction", "Place of Interest", 
                                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    for (int i = 0; i<POIBook.length; i++) {            
                    
        if(search.equalsIgnoreCase(POIBook[i].type)) {
                                                
            Object[] options = { "Next >", "Return to Menu" };
            
            int select = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Place of interest " + (i+1) + " of 8\n" + POIBook[i].display() + 
                         "\nPress Next for next Place of Interest \n" + "To return, press Return to Menu \n", "Display Places of Interest in Sequence",
                         JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, POIBook[i].icon, options, options[1]);   
                
                if (select == 1) {
                    
                    return;
                    
                }

        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include your expected output in the question, instead of attaching a link.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Where do the `1` and `3` in `1 of 3` come from?  I think we're missing the larger context.

Comment: I simply didn't understand your question!

Comment: Hi, have edited the post to add in the context. Hope it helps clarify!